# SAS code to identify different values in multiple rows according to one subject

Tags: sas

the following data structure is given:

| ID | CASE | VALUE | DUMMY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 4736 | E10 | 1 |
| 123 | 1254 | N65 | 0 |
| 123 | 0997 | E11 | 1 |
| 123 | 7655 | x | 0 |
| 987 | 1234 | x | 0 |
| 987 | 6376 | E10 | 1 |
| 987 | 0980 | E18 | 0 |

I want to know: How can i create a new variable that includes if someone actually has the combination of E10 AND E11 (0,1) as follows:

| ID | CASE | VALUE | DUMMY | Has the combination |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 4736 | E10 | 1 | 1 |
| 123 | 1254 | N65 | 0 | 1 |
| 123 | 0997 | E11 | 1 | 1 |
| 123 | 7655 | x | 0 | 1 |
| 987 | 1234 | x | 0 | 0 |
| 987 | 6376 | E10 | 1 | 0 |
| 987 | 0980 | E18 | 0 | 0 |

Thanks in advance,

PP

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could it be that one specific ID has multiple times the E10 or E11 value?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, thats possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption is that the data is already sorted by `id`.

```
data want;
    do until (last.id);
        set have;
        by id;
        if value = 'E10' then E10 = 1;
        if value = 'E11' then E11 = 1;
    end;

    do until (last.id);
        set have;
        by id;
        if E10 = 1 and E11 = 1 then combination = 1;
        else combination = 0;
        output;
    end;

    drop E:;
run;
```

```
 id   case  value  dummy  combination
123   4736   E10     1        1
123   1254   N65     0        1
123   997    E11     1        1
123   7655    x      0        1
987   1234    x      0        0
987   6376   E10     1        0
987   980    E18     0        0
```